# Incorrect evaluations on Random Forest in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, random-forest, apache-spark-sql

I am running a prediction using Logistic Regression and Random Forest on telecom churn data set.

Please find here the code snippet from my notebook:

```
data=spark.read.csv("D:\Shashank\CBA\Pyspark\Telecom_Churn_Data_SingTel.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
data.show(3)
```

[This link is to show the kind of data i am dealing with on a high level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzkLl.jpg)

```
data=data.drop("State").drop("Area Code").drop("Phone Number")
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorAssembler
intlPlanIndex = StringIndexer(inputCol="International Plan", outputCol="International Plan Index")
voiceMailPlanIndex = StringIndexer(inputCol="Voice mail Plan", outputCol="Voice mail Plan Index")
churnIndex = StringIndexer(inputCol="Churn", outputCol="label")
othercols=["Account Length", "Num of Voice mail Messages","Total Day Minutes", "Total Day Calls", "Total day Charge","Total Eve Minutes","Total Eve Calls","Total Eve Charge","Total Night Minutes","Total Night Calls ","Total Night Charge","Total International Minutes","Total Intl  Calls","Total Intl Charge","Number Customer Service calls "]
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols= ['International Plan Index'] + ['Voice mail Plan Index'] + othercols, outputCol="features")
(train, test) = data.randomSplit([0.8,0.2])
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
lrObj = LogisticRegression(labelCol='label', featuresCol='features')
from pyspark.ml.pipeline import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[intlPlanIndex, voiceMailPlanIndex, churnIndex, assembler, lrObj])
lrModel = pipeline.fit(train)
prediction_train = lrModel.transform(train)
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
lr_Evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
lr_Evaluator.evaluate(prediction_train)
```

[This image shows the result on evaluation using logistic Regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhTgz.jpg)

I then repeat the same using a **Random Forest classification** model:
and I evaluate to **94.4%**
My result is sort of like this:
[Link to my Random Forest evaluation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exjtl.jpg)

Everything looks ok until now.
But I get curious to see how things actually are being predicted, so i print the values of my prediction using the code below:

```
selected = prediction_1.select("features", "Label", "Churn", "prediction")
for row in selected.collect():
    print(row)
```

The result i get is sort of like this in the screenshot below:
[Link to image that shows the 2 results printed out for manual analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oXDM.jpg)

I then copy both the cells as shown from the above link into a compactor to see if my predicted values are different. (I expect there to be some difference, since the evaluation for Random forest turned out to be better)

But the comparison on any tool showed that the predictions are the same. Yet, the result on evaluation shows a difference 83.6% on LogisticRegression and 94.4% using RandomForest.

Why is there no difference in the 2 sets of data that i have generated from 2 different models when the ultimate evaluation using MuticlassClassificationEvaluator gives me different probabilities ?

Comment: You should explain what is the link you are pointing to. Something like "Here is an image of the results", or "You can find the running code on the link below".

Comment: Hi @Jeremie, This is my first time on stack, i apologize for the lack of information. I have edited my post, i hope this helps clarify my question.

Comment: Welcome!! No need to apologize! It’s the best for us developers!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be interested in `metricName="accuracy"`

```
predictions = model.transform(test)
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="indexedLabel", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy")
accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
```

For more info refer the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html).

Comment: Hi @Prem, From my limited understanding, i don't think i am worried about the metric, but curious about the lack of difference between the predicted quantities from the 2 classification models:
selected = prediction_1.select("features", "Label", "Churn", "prediction")
for row in selected.collect():
    print(row)

Comment: @Shashank can you pls run the suggested code and then confirm about the `accuracy` of both models?

Comment: Sorry guys there is a difference in the data. The mistake was mine, i did not copy all the data in my cell from Jupyter.

Comment: No problem :) I would suggest not to delete this question as it might be helpful to someone who will be looking for LR/ RF implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This question is no longer relevant since i am able to see the difference in the predictions which is in line with the accuracy predicted under each model.
The question came up because the data i copied from my Jupyter notebook was incomplete.

Thanks and appreciate your time.